# passing object as an argument of function

Tags: python, object, dll, ctypes

There is a function from a DLL (C language) `link("parameters", &connection);` which takes a string parameter and initializes a connection.

There is a function `connect(connection)`, where `connection` is the object initialized with a call to `link()`.

I pass Python connection object to function `connect()` as an argument

```
connection_t = ctypes.c_uint32
link = mydll.link
link.argtypes=(ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(connection_t) )
connect = mydll.connect
connect.argtypes=(connection_t,)
...
connection = connection_t()
link ("localhost: 5412", ctypes.byref(connection))
...
```

But if I transfer the 'connection' object to any other function of mydll library, the function returns a value, but the value is incorrect.

```
func=mydll.func
status_t=ctypes.c_uint32
status=status_t()
func.argtypes=(ctypes.c_ulong,ctypes.POINTER(status_t))
result=func(connection, ctypes.byref(status))
```

In this example `result=0`, but in the C-variant of this code I receive a correct value (not 0)

Why?

Comment: Are you sure you should be looking at `result` and not `status`?

Comment: `connection_t` is a `ctypes.c_uint32`, but the first `func.argtypes` is a `ctypes.c_ulong`?

Comment: yak, sorry, i mean 'status' value. But if 'status' is incorrect then 'result' value is incorrect too.

Comment: martineau, i corrected the first 'func.argtypes' (connection_t is a ctypes.c_uint32), but it did not help

Comment: The code as posted looks ok.  Post the exact C header definitions for the functions and the code to init `mydll`.  Are you using CDLL or WinDLL to init mydll?

Comment: 'link(const char* set, conn_type* connection );' and 
'func(conn_type* connection, uint32_t* status);'. I use mydll=CDLL("C:\\mydll.dll")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment describing the C apis:

```
link(const char* set, conn_type* connection );
func(conn_type* connection, uint32_t* status);
```

Since func takes a pointer to a connection type, the code should be something like:

```
mydll=ctypes.CDLL('mydll')
connection_t = ctypes.c_uint32
link = mydll.link
link.argtypes=(ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(connection_t) )
connection = connection_t()
link("localhost: 5412", ctypes.byref(connection))

func=mydll.func
status_t=ctypes.c_uint32
status=status_t()
func.argtypes=(ctypes.POINTER(connection_t),ctypes.POINTER(status_t))
result=func(ctypes.byref(connection), ctypes.byref(status))
```